# Backup/Restore of Firebird SQL Server 3.0.2 is slow on Windows Server 2016

Tags: firebird, windows-server-2016, solid-state-drive, firebird-3.0

I have installed Firebird 3.0.2 SQL database on my Windows Server 2016. No other software has been installed yet.

I'm using Superserver mode and an SSD drive.

When I just copy my database file of size 6 GB, it is done in 20-30 seconds (same disk).

But when I execute backup it takes 20-30 minutes. Restore is about the same amount of time. Together 40-60 minutes.

And there is strange thing: backup/restore process (gbak.exe) does not use full power of CPUs and HDD. It is using only ~20% . I don't understand why.

I think it should be something in configuration right? But I kept everything in default values.

Very important thing: I am new in Windows Server 2016 so I have no idea what I am doing.

Any ideas?

Comment: GBAK makes a logical backup of the database, which is why it takes longer than a filesystem copy, but a factor 60 seems excessive. Also note that gbak is essentially a single-threaded process, and an IO-bound one at that. It will not be able to generate more load than a single core (give or take). The defaults in `firebird.conf`  for buffers, and other temporary space is rather conservative, so tweaking that might help as well.

Comment: In my case it takes around 30 minutes to restore 250 MB database from local backup to LAN server. I dont remember times for backup but it is much lower (2 - 3 minutes). Firebird local version is 2.5.8 and Firebird server version is 2.5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that it is about configuration of **Power Options**.

Windows Server 2016 is after installation set for Balanced Power Plan.

I changed it to High performance and results are highly better. (backup drops from 30 minutes to 6 minutes)

More details you can find here: https://serverfault.com/a/797473

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to the GBAK option

```
-service localhost:service_mgr
```

it is a speed demon :-)

Answer (score 0):

To find the restore bottleneck in Firebird 3 you should add the detail protokoll option:

```
-v -stat TDRW Filename

-v       (Verbose output of what GBAK is doing)
-stat    (Runtime statistics in its verbose output)
  T      (Total time) 
  D      (Total delta) 
  R      (Page reads)
  W      (Page writes)
```